# How get the "data" at the server side

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, api, rest

I have the next config into my angularjs:

```
var config={ //config post
    method:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost/APIREST/controllersencillo", 
    params: {tabla : "PintaMonas"}, //without id is insert, with id is update
    data: {PMcolor: "Azul tostado", PMpartes: "Un poquito de las orjeas y un bigote a lo Dali, quizas le alegre la cara", PMcosteTotal: "445" }
  }
```

When i call to the server work perfectly, this isn't the problem. The problem it's how get the **data**.

My function POST of my server is:

```
 $arrayDatos = $this->post('datosSend');
            echo 'Tipe of data: '.gettype($arrayDatos);
                    print_r($arrayDatos);

                    die();
```

Any solution? I didn't find anything similar in the web (include stack overflow).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `$arrayDatos = $_POST;`

Comment: return: "Tipe of data: array <br> Array ( )" XD

Comment: what returns print_r($_POST); ?

Comment: That means you don't create any post request.